# How to make text vertically center?

Tags: react-native

sample project: https://snack.expo.io/SyyO8XxbZ

I am trying to make the text center in the TouchableOpacity component, I had tried to use lineHeight: 50 but I just don't want to set it manually. Besides, I also tried to use flex:1 and justifyContent: 'center' in the container but it just screw up my intended layout.

Please help!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Option extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeOption: this.props.options[0],
    };
  }
  updateActiveOption = (activeOption) => {
    this.setState({
      activeOption,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          marginTop:100
        }}
      >
        {this.props.options.map((option) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 5,
              backgroundColor: this.state.activeOption === option ? 'lightgrey' : 'white',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: this.state.activeOption === option ? 'grey' : 'lightgrey',
              overflow: 'hidden',
              justifyContent: 'center',//can't work
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.onChange(option);
              this.updateActiveOption(option);
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                //lineHeight: 50,
                textAlign: 'center',
                width: 150,
                height: 50,
                color: 'black',
              }}
            >
              {option}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      < Option
        options={['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}
        onChange={(option) => {
          console.log(option);
        }}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

class Option extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeOption: this.props.options[0],
    };
  }
  updateActiveOption = (activeOption) => {
    this.setState({
      activeOption,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          marginTop:100
        }}
      >
        {this.props.options.map((option) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 5,
              backgroundColor: this.state.activeOption === option ? 'lightgrey' : 'white',
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: this.state.activeOption === option ? 'grey' : 'lightgrey',
              overflow: 'hidden',
              height: 50,
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.props.onChange(option);
              this.updateActiveOption(option);
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                //lineHeight: 50,
                textAlign: 'center',
                width: 150,
                color: 'black',
              }}
            >
              {option}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      < Option
        options={['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}
        onChange={(option) => {
          console.log(option);
        }}/>
    );
  }
}
```